# SQL Server: Horizontal Partitioning vs. Foreign Keys

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, partitioning

So I recently began working for an established client.  They have an existing database and they want me to set up a partitioning scheme in their development database so that they can see the impact it has on performance.  (They believe that it will improve performance to "archive" old data by moving it to another partition.  From my analysis, I don't believe that the performance will improve in any significant way.  But they want me to move ahead, anyway.)  And so I've come to a situation where I have `TableA` and `TableB` with a Many to Many relationship.  The Join table between them, we'll call `TableJ`.

`TableA` has a clustered primary key on a `uniqueidentifier` column.  And so `TableJ` has a Foreign Key constraint that references `TableA.IDColumn`.

So here's my dilemma...  In order to partition `TableA` on a partition column (we'll call it `PartCol`) `PartCol` needs to be included in the clustered index.  My plan was to remove the clustered primary key on `IDColumn` and replace it with a nonclustered primary key on `PartCol` and `IDColumn`, then create a clustered index on `PartCol` in order to establish the horizontal partitioning.  In order to do all that, I have to drop the Foreign Keys that reference `TableA.IDColumn` and then recreate them when I'm done.  But when I try to recreate the FK Constraint, I get an error that looks like:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 There are no primary or candidate
>   keys in the referenced table 'MySchema.TableA' that match the
>   referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_TableJ_TableA'.

Which makes sense, since my key is no longer defined as being unique on `IDColumn`.  Because of the way partitioning works, I can't have a unique constraint that does not include the partition column.  But if that's the case, then how do I support tables, like these, that have a M-to-M relationship?  It seems to me that this would be a common issue.  So I'm guessing that there's a solution that I've overlooked.

Thanks, in advance.

Additional notes, in case people need to know:  The largest of these tables have 20M+ records.  Not so big that partitioning *needs* to be implemented, but not so small as to immediately conclude that it's unwise.  Also, I have about 20 tables on which I'll be trying to implement partitioning.  And this is for SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it looks like my only course of action is to create all my unique indexes/constraints on the [PRIMARY] filegroup instead of on the partition scheme.  (Thus making them non-aligned indexes, which will interfere with partition switching, if we ever decide to implement partition switching.  But it looks like that's not a concern in my case.)  Then I can rebuild my FK constraints exactly like they were before the partitioning.

I'm not going to mark this as the answer, yet, since I don't particularly like it and am hoping that someone else out there has a better solution.

Comment: Okay, after oodles more research, I've confirmed (at least to my satisfaction) that this is my best solution.  Partitioning OLTP databases often seems to run into this issue.  And using non-aligned indexes (which prevent the ability to Switch partitions) is the only way to have a unique index that doe snot include the partition column.